# Why is bundler using an old version of ruby, and not recognizing new gems that are installed?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, rubymine

In my Heroku/Sinatra app I set up my gemfile with Ruby 1.8.7 and then later used RVM to set my default to 2.0.0. Now when I try and install any new gems such Sinatra-flash or Pony, the gems aren't recognized or found when I require them in my main.rb file.

When I add gem "pony" in my gemfile I get a popup message saying:

```
Gem 'pony' is not available in SDK 'ruby-1.8.7-p385'
```

even though I've installed it. When I type `gem list` into the terminal, it returns all the gems I've installed that aren't being recognized as installed in my program.

If I add `require 'sinatra/flash'` or `require 'pony'` in my main.rb, I get a message:

```
no such file to load
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this, this has been driving me nuts.

Edited:

Using command `sudo gem install 'gemname'`

When I enter `rvm info` I get back

```
ruby :
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p195"
    date:         "2013-05-14"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin12.3.0"
    patchlevel:   "2013-05-14 revision 40734"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195"
    ruby:         "/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/adam419/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin/[["
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195:/Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Edit: After I enter 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0' and then 'bundle install'

I get;

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:songs adam419$ rvm use ruby-2.0.0
Using /Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
Adams-MacBook-Pro:songs adam419$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'sinatra/flash (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

After changing from gem "sinatra/flash" to gem "sinatra-flash" and then running bundle install

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Using addressable (2.2.8) 
Installing daemons (1.1.9) 
Using data_objects (0.10.12) 
Using dm-core (1.2.0) 
Using dm-do-adapter (1.2.0) 
Installing dm-migrations (1.2.0) 
Using do_sqlite3 (0.10.12) 
Using dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0) 
Installing eventmachine (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-protection (1.5.0) 
Using sass (3.2.9) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sinatra (1.4.2) 
Using sinatra-flash (0.3.0) 
Installing temple (0.6.5) 
Installing slim (1.3.9) 
Installing thin (1.5.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Current Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "sinatra"
gem "slim"
gem "sass"
gem "dm-core"
gem "sinatra-flash"
gem "dm-migrations"
gem "thin"
gem "pg", :group => :production
gem "dm-postgres-adapter", :group => :production
gem "dm-sqlite-adapter", :group => :development
```

Gemlock file dependencies

```
DEPENDENCIES
  dm-core
  dm-migrations
  dm-postgres-adapter
  dm-sqlite-adapter
  pg
  sass
  sinatra
  sinatra-flash
  slim
  thin
```

Comment: I think for some reason when I changed my default from 1.8.7 that comes stock on the mac os x I'm using, all new gems I'm installing are being applied to the old version not being used by the ruby-2.0.0-p195 I have set as default right now.

Comment: You're missing some essential information, such as "what command are you using to install new gems?" Also, type [`rvm info`](https://rvm.io/rvm/info/) at the command-line and append that information into your question by editing it.

Comment: Try to run it with `rvmsudo gem install pony`

Comment: `rvmsudo` is a bad idea. Just run `gem install` to keep out of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

By using `sudo gem install pony` you're triggering the system Ruby install which is different from RVM's version. Do not use `sudo`. Just make sure that RVM is loaded, then use the correct version of your ruby:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0
```

Then run bundler:

```
bundle install
```

This should give you the full environment.

Comment: Diffeerent gem name: `gem install sinatra-flash`

Comment: After I changed to sinatra-flash from sinatra/flash, there's still a message saying the Gem 'sinatra-flash' is not available in SDK 'ruby-1.8.7-p385' when I hover over it in my gemfile, and after bundler install successfully installed the gem, I'll update my question with the response

Comment: Did you sudo bundle your gems? Asking because it wants your password in between. The gem name is sinatra-flash and then you `require sinatra/flash`.

Comment: Nope, I just entered "bundle install" which still prompted me for my password, when I put "gem 'sinatra-flash'" in my gemfile it underlines it with that message Gem 'sinatra-flash' is not available in SDK 'ruby-1.8.7-p385', and when I write require 'sinatra/flash' in my main.rb file it says no such file to load

Comment: Just updated it with my gemfile, thanks a lot for the help btw

Comment: looks ok to me. Maybe your rvm install is busted? Implode and rebuild sometimes helps. Does it work on Heroku?

Comment: I haven't pushed this to heroku because since it's not even recognizing the gems on development it breaks the whole program with just the require statements never mind the flash code I have. Could you elaborate on how to implode and rebuild?

Comment: Whats strange is that when I go to settings in RubyMine, it's highlighted as using the 2.0.0 version (not global) and clearly lists the gems that I want. But for some reason, in the actual project it's saying that they dont exist in the 1.8.7, which they don't when I look at 1.8.7's gems.

Comment: So I went into 1.8.7 and installed sinatra-flash inside rubymine settings and now it works. The question is why is my project using 1.8.7 as supposed to 2.0.0?

Comment: rubymine possibly picks up the wrong version. Try using your project on the command line. Then everything should work fine. IDEs sometimes have problems with rvm.

Comment: At this point, it sounds more like a RubyMine problem than a problem with rvm or bundler. You might want to add a tag to the question so that some RubyMine experts see it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i deleted my rubymine .idea file and now its working fine.